# Simfony2 phpunit -c app Failed asserting that false is true

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have a code to implement a blog in my website. I want to check whether it is functional by issuing in the console: phpunit -c app.

I get a a result:

There was 1 failure:
1) Blog\CoreBundle\Tests\Controller\PostControllerTest::testIndex

No response

Failed asserting that false is true.
C:\xampp\htdocs\escribe\src\Blog\CoreBundle\Tests\Controller\PostControllerTesphp:21

Here is the simple code I implemented to check the client:

```
<?php
namespace Blog\CoreBundle\Tests\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
/**
 * Class PostControllerTest
 */
class PostControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * Tests posts index
     */
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');
        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful(), 'No response');
    }
}
```

Im building this on symfony2 2.5
Thank you in advanced for your help.

Comment: `isSuccessful()` simply checks if the status code of the response is between `200` and `300`. In your case it seems that it's not...I'm not sure I get your issue (maybe you should have posted the code of the tested action?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that the page is well-formatted by checking some elements in the page:

```php
# check that there is a <html> tag (this is an example, in real life it's pretty useless)
$this->assertEquals(
    1,
    $crawler->filter('html:contains("Blog")')->count()
);

# check that the page <title> contains "Blog"
$this->assertEquals(
    1,
    $crawler->filter('title:contains("Blog")')->count()
);

# check that the page have articles (use your own selector)
$this->assertGreaterThan(
    0,
    $crawler->filter('#content div.article')->count()
);
```

See the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#your-first-functional-test) for more examples and the [PHPUnit documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html) for a list of all the assertions.

Answer (score 0):

thanks A.L. I took a break and somehow just today got the answer. It was a really silly mistake. The route inside app/config/routing.yml was wrongly defined for other controllers. Thanks for your support.